# ConEmu run {cmd} instead of cmd.exe

Tags: conemu

When I run cmd in the "windows start/search" then ConEmu opens with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe".
Then, if I open a new tab then it opens properly a new `{Shell:cmd}`

How can I set it up, that when I run cmd in the command line it should open a new ConCmu window with {Shell:cmd} by default?

[image]

This is what I get when I type `cmd`:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you run `ConEmu` instead of `cmd`?

Comment: Good question :) I was wondering if it's possible to run cmd but still get the same effect. I have all kind of short-cuts where cmd is already integrated.

Comment: When you run `cmd.exe`, ConEmu runs `cmd.exe`. Why it should run powershell, Quake or whatever else? ;) The task `{cmd}` could actually contains any command and if you what to run something, you should run that command. Or simple `ConEmu.exe` if you have properly configured startup task.